# Timing of dialog pop-up up after database call

Tags: java, android

I have a dialog that I need to pop-up after I'd loaded data from the Firebase DB as I want the pop-up to contain information from the database.

My pop-up is written as so;

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setMessage("Check the match details are correct;\n\n-Home Team - " + diaHomeTeam + "\n-Away Team - " + diaAwayTeam +"\n-Time / Date - " + diaDate + " / " + diaTime + " \n-Pitch number - " + diaPitch)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //do things
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

And is inside my public void onViewCreated. My database call is inside the public void onAttach, and no matter when I try to call the dialog box it always returns null as its executing before the data from the DB has been returned.

I'm new to Android development and want to find the information about the execution ordering of the methods, so I could determine what gets called first and what allows me to call the dialog box after I have captured the database values in my class variables beforehand (or do I need to do this in the constructor?).

All help is appreciated.

Full fragment code below;

```
package uk.co.futsalselect.app.futsalselect;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.MutableData;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.Transaction;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class refscorecard_fragment extends Fragment {
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    ListView listViewLive;
    ImageView stopWatch;
    Integer gameOn = 0;

    public refscorecard_fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static refscorecard_fragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        refscorecard_fragment fragment = new refscorecard_fragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        listViewLive = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listViewAsItHappens);
    }

    public void updateDBMatches(final String fieldUpd, final Object valueUpd) {
        String getArgument = getArguments().getString("matchid");
        final DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Matches").child(getArgument);
        ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                updates.put(fieldUpd, valueUpd);
                ref.updateChildren(updates);
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_refscorecard, container, false);

        AlertDialog.Builder diaBox = alert();
        diaBox.show();

        //Home Score Button
        Button homeScoreBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnHomeTeam);
        homeScoreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Button homeScoreBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnHomeTeam);
                String homeScore = (String) homeScoreBtn.getText();
                final int homeScoreAdd = Integer.valueOf(homeScore.toString()) + 1;
                homeScoreBtn.setText(String.valueOf(homeScoreAdd));
                updateDBMatches("homeScore", homeScoreAdd);
            }
        });

        //Away Score Button
        Button awayScoreBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAwayTeam);
        awayScoreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Button awayScoreBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnAwayTeam);
                String awayScore = (String) awayScoreBtn.getText();
                final int awayScoreAdd = Integer.valueOf(awayScore.toString()) + 1;
                awayScoreBtn.setText(String.valueOf(awayScoreAdd));
                updateDBMatches("awayScore", awayScoreAdd);
            }
        });

        //Away Fouls Button
        Button awayFoulsBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAwayFouls);
        awayFoulsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Button awayFoulsBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnAwayFouls);
                String awayFouls = (String) awayFoulsBtn.getText();
                final int awayFoulsAdd = Integer.valueOf(awayFouls.toString()) + 1;
                awayFoulsBtn.setText(String.valueOf(awayFoulsAdd));

                if (Integer.valueOf(awayFoulsAdd) > 5) {
                    awayFoulsBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.airhornsoundeffect);
                    mp.start();
                }
                updateDBMatches("awayFouls", awayFoulsAdd);
            }
        });

        //Home Fouls Button
        Button homeFoulsBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnHomeFouls);
        homeFoulsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Button homeFoulsBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnHomeFouls);
                String homeFouls = (String) homeFoulsBtn.getText();
                final int homeFoulsAdd = Integer.valueOf(homeFouls.toString()) + 1;
                homeFoulsBtn.setText(String.valueOf(homeFoulsAdd));

                if (Integer.valueOf(homeFoulsAdd) > 5) {
                    homeFoulsBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.airhornsoundeffect);
                    mp.start();
                }
                updateDBMatches("homeFouls", homeFoulsAdd);
            }
        });

        //Home Score Min Button
        Button homeScoreMinBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnMinHomeScore);
        homeScoreMinBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Button homeScoreBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnHomeTeam);
                String homeScoreMin = (String) homeScoreBtn.getText();

                if (Integer.valueOf(homeScoreMin.toString()) > 0) {
                    final int homeScoreAdd = Integer.valueOf(homeScoreMin.toString()) -1;
                    homeScoreBtn.setText(String.valueOf(homeScoreAdd));
                    updateDBMatches("homeScore", homeScoreAdd);
                }
            }
        });

        //Away Score Min Button
        Button awayScoreMinBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnMinAwayScore);
        awayScoreMinBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Button awayScoreBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnAwayTeam);
                String awayScoreMin = (String) awayScoreBtn.getText();
                if (Integer.valueOf(awayScoreMin.toString()) > 0) {
                    final int awayScoreAdd = Integer.valueOf(awayScoreMin.toString()) - 1;
                    awayScoreBtn.setText(String.valueOf(awayScoreAdd));
                    updateDBMatches("awayScore", awayScoreAdd);
                }
            }
        });

        //Countdown clock button
        Button counterBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.matchCountDownBtn);
        counterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                updateDBMatches("played", 1);
                final Button counterBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.matchCountDownBtn);
                new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000){
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                        stopWatch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        counterBtn.setEnabled(false);
                        long l = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                        int i = (int) l;
                        counterBtn.setText(secondsToString(i));
                        gameOn = 1;
                    }
                    public  void onFinish(){
                        gameOn = 0;
                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.airhornsoundeffect);
                        mp.start();
                        //Disable score buttons
                        Button homeFoulsBtnDisabled = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnHomeFouls);
                        Button awayFoulsBtnDisabled = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnAwayFouls);
                        homeFoulsBtnDisabled.setEnabled(false);
                        awayFoulsBtnDisabled.setEnabled(false);
                        Button counterBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.matchCountDownBtn);
                        stopWatch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        counterBtn.setText("FULL TIME");
                        updateDBMatches("played", 2);
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (gameOn == 1) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to cancel the match?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setTitle("Cancel match?")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //do things
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
        }
    }


    private String secondsToString(int pTime) {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", pTime / 60, pTime % 60);
    }

    private String diaHomeTeam;
    private String diaAwayTeam;
    private String diaDate;
    private String diaTime;
    private String diaPitch;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        String getArgument = getArguments().getString("matchid");
        DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.child("Matches");
        Query gameQuery = ref.orderByChild("gameID").equalTo(getArgument);
        gameQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    TextView homeTeamSetTxt = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtRefHomeTeam);
                    TextView awayTeamSetTxt = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtRefAwayTeam);
                    TextView dataSetTxt = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtRefDate);
                    TextView timeSetTxt = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtRefTime);
                    TextView pitchSetTxt = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtRefPitch);
                    Button homeScoreBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnHomeTeam);
                    Button awayScoreBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnAwayTeam);
                    Button homeFoulBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnHomeFouls);
                    Button awayFoulBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnAwayFouls);
                    homeTeamSetTxt.setText(singleSnapshot.child("homeTeam").getValue().toString());
                    awayTeamSetTxt.setText(singleSnapshot.child("awayTeam").getValue().toString());
                    dataSetTxt.setText(singleSnapshot.child("date").getValue().toString());
                    timeSetTxt.setText(singleSnapshot.child("time").getValue().toString());
                    pitchSetTxt.setText("Pitch " + singleSnapshot.child("pitch").getValue().toString());
                    homeScoreBtn.setText(singleSnapshot.child("homeScore").getValue().toString());
                    awayScoreBtn.setText(singleSnapshot.child("awayScore").getValue().toString());
                    homeFoulBtn.setText(singleSnapshot.child("homeFouls").getValue().toString());
                    awayFoulBtn.setText(singleSnapshot.child("awayFouls").getValue().toString());

                    stopWatch = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imgStopWatch);
                    stopWatch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    diaHomeTeam = singleSnapshot.child("homeTeam").getValue().toString();
                    diaAwayTeam = singleSnapshot.child("awayTeam").getValue().toString();
                    diaDate = singleSnapshot.child("date").getValue().toString();
                    diaTime = singleSnapshot.child("time").getValue().toString();
                    diaPitch = singleSnapshot.child("pitch").getValue().toString();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });
    }



    private AlertDialog.Builder alert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setMessage("Check the match details are correct;\n\n-Home Team - " + diaHomeTeam + "\n-Away Team - " + diaAwayTeam + "\n-Time / Date - " + diaDate + " / " + diaTime + " \n-Pitch number - " + diaPitch)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle("Checklist")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //do things
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        return builder;
        //alert.show();
        //myQuittingDialogBox.setIcon(R.drawable.);
    }



    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events. The ValueChangeListener is called once everytime the listener is added to a DatabaseaReference object, and subsequently when data is changed. So when you land your fragment, add a ValueChangedListener and create the dialog in the listeners implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have posted all the code from the fragment.

You can see the fragment lifecycle here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

But you want to create and show the Dialog after you receive the information from the DB.

Comment: Thanks, thats really useful. The problem I have is that no matter where I call the dialog above it always gets created before the DB call. The DB call is happening in the onAttach, I call the dialog onStart, still it doesn't work as expected :(

Comment: I'll edit the original post now with the information :)

Comment: Try to call the Dialog in the "onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)". It should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Diogo, that worked great, I thought I had tried that previously but clearly not. Thankss